# A synchronizes with B - which direction is the synchronization?

Tags: technical, logic

I read in a document that A will synchronize with B after a procedure.

My question is:

After the synchronization, will A be equal with B, or will B be equal with A?

Edit:

I want to clarify why I ask this question.

The document I am referring to, instructs me that I should change the content of A.

After the change, A will then synchronize with B. I find this a bit odd, as my change would be reverted. I would expect the synchronization would be in the other direction.

I need some clarification on this matter. I not yet sure if the procedure is correctly described.

Comment: After the *synchronization*, A and B will be identical (so the answer to your question "*will A be equal with B, or will B be equal with A?*" is "*yes*"), but A will have changed, and B won't have.

Comment: The implication is that it is A which will change ('synchronize') to match B. To make the statement so ambiguous that one could not tell which entity was being changed to match the other, you could write "After [the procedure], A and B will be synchronized" or "After [the procedure], A and B will synchronize".

Comment: Thanks, but why comments? These are actual answers.

Comment: *Synchronize* used this way is malapropism gone wild, that the malapropism has become common and accepted use.

Comment: To take a different example, if I tell you "Mix sugar with milk" you might imagine a bowl of milk and that you are supposed to put sugar in. If I say "Mix milk with sugar", you might imagine a pile of sugar and that you are supposed to pour milk over it. However, if the amounts of sugar and milk are the same in both experiments, is there really a difference?? I think choosing one order or the other is probably just a matter of preference, convention or emphasis. If you stop and think about it there is not a functional difference.

Comment: @Brandin, this do not apply in this case, as the equivalent would an alchemist turning led to gold, or gold to led. It the latter case, he would be rather unpopular.

Comment: @Dogeatcatworld In the example of "into" (e.g. turn lead into gold), the order of the words has a functional difference. But with 'with' there is no such difference. Mixing lead with gold is the same as mixing gold with lead.

Comment: So it could be possible that "A synchronized with B" and "B synchronized with A" do not give any information about the end result, gold or led?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sychronization, **A** will be *made equal to* **B**.

So it seems the documentation is inconsistent. Asking you to change A makes sense only if **B** will then be synchronized with **A**.

Answer (score 0):

The implication is that it is A which will change ('synchronize') to match B.

To make the statement so ambiguous that one could not tell which entity was being changed to match the other, you could write "After [the procedure], A and B will be synchronized" or "After [the procedure], A and B will synchronize".